# How to support credit card payment with paypal

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm exhausted in searching a clear answer in paypal's documents.

Here is the problem I met: I created my app under REST APIs and it works fine. However,when I wanted to pay with a credit card, I found it didn't work out since it just supports a few countries to do so(I'm in HongKong).

Then I changed my app to Classic APIs, which seemed to support using credit card in my country, but under the guiding of its official documents and demo, I can't even find a place to use credit card.

What should I do next if I want to support credit card payment in my app? Should I use REST or Classic, payment or advancedPayment?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

So no, unfortunately it is not currently available in the HongKong.

Answer (score 0):

According to PayPal's feedback email:
Credit card payment for Mobile SDK in not available in HongKong.
So it is impossible to implement credit card payment inside your app.
  There is another solution allows buyer to pay with credit card directly, it is called Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution.
  It is a website solution, the same as REST and Classic API, but it always allow buyer to pay with credit card.
You can contact our customer service center for more information.
Below is the integration guide of Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution.:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_AU/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_au.pdf